# Is it possible to create a custom keyboard with Swift without forcing the user to attach it through Setting screen?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am creating a custom keyboard using Swift, but I don't want to force the user to go to Setting screen and attach the keyboard. Is there a way that I can avoid that?

Comment: In your own app or in other people's apps?

Comment: it is for my own app. can you provide a sample code to display my keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In your own app

Yeah, sure. Just create a view and use that instead of calling the keyboard. You can probably override `inputView` on text inputs to automagically make your keyboard appear.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html

## In other apps in iOS

Not a chance. Unless you do it for jailbroken devices only (don't do it for jailbroken devices).

Comment: It is for my app only, can you give me a hint how can I override the inputView in order to display my keyboard?

Comment: `inputView` is a property of `UITextField`. Just set the property on it to be what you want. You will also need to work out how to pass letter presses etc so it acts like a keyboard too.

Comment: @Carlos take a look at the documentation for `UIInputView` looks like that's a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, you nailed it.

Comment: @Carlos no worries. Happy to help.